# How Do You Prove That This Puzzle Is Physically Solvable?

Tags: mathematics, physics

[image][image]

https://www.reddit.com/r/BeAmazed/comments/fyt7x9/it_seems_to_be_impossible_but_it_gets_done/?ref=share&ref_source=link

The goal of the puzzle is to remove the wooden stick from the jar by fiddling with it.

Is it possible to mathematically/physically prove that the puzzle is solvable, given the precise dimensions of all the components?

Puzzle being assembled, if interested: https://youtu.be/3tjMDbS2nz0?t=178

Comment: Are any of the dimensions known?

Comment: Is there a video of the puzzle being assembled?

Comment: I have edited the main answer to contain a video of the puzzle being assembled.

Comment: Also, the dimensions aren't known. I was talking more on a theoretical basis.

Comment: You can find Chris Ramsay solving it here. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VWKt4AOM5Yw